# Bug in compiler for C# 8 switch?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Does anyone know why the compiler would complain here?

All of the above parts of the `switch` work perfectly fine.  As soon as I add another line like "Bell", that line and all the rest of them fail with a compiler error.

I have restarted Visual Studio, rebooted, the issue persists.

I have tried moving them to the top of the `switch` and the compiler still complains like this.

If I remove these lines the code works perfectly fine.

[image: Compiler Issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be looking at the fact that you've switched from using `()` to using `{}`, right at the point where the error is.

I don't know enough about C# to know which one it should be, but my knowledge of languages in general leads me to believe one or the other is wrong.

Comment: Stupid, stupid stupid me.  I've been staring at the screen too long.